# Syntax of double brackets double quotes in excel

Tags: excel

I don't understand the syntax of the following logical test in an if statement in excel:

```
if(cell designator <>"", value if true, value if false.
```

Could someone explain what the brackets and quotes are testing for?

Comment: An example would be, `=IF(A3 <> "", "Non-blank", "Blank")`. The value of the current cell would be the string "Non-blank" if `A3` is not blank, and "Blank" otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

`<>""` Excel's way of checking if the string contains a ***valid value/string***. It's almost the same as `=IF(LEN(A1)=0...`.

However, this will not check for you if a cell is entirely blank. A perfect example would be entering just `'` in `A1`. Input `=A1<>""` in `B1` and it will return `TRUE`.

Now try `=ISBLANK(A1)`, and it will return `FALSE`. Hence, why I used the term *valid*.

Comment: today is your day, congrats on 3k:)

Comment: @simoco: Thanks. First time I got the maximum rep per day (Mortarboard as well) AND got the cast close/reopen vote ability. Too slow, compared to your advancement though, lol. :) This might be the day I answered a lot compared to just exploring a lot. :D

Answer (score 0):

The double quotes indicates a blank cell.  So it could be read as

```
if (cell designator is blank, true, false)
```

Answer (score 0):

The <> operator means NOT EQUAL.
Therefore it is checking if the cell's value is not an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

`<>` means Not equal to

`""` means empty or blank

The whole expression is saying `"If value of given cell is blank/empty then result1 (true value) otherwise result2 (false value)"`